# npm publish patch for earlier major version

Tags: npm

I can't seem to find information about how npm works with branches within a repository.

Suppose an npm package is currently versioned at: **1.0.5**

A major change requires a version change from **1.0.5** => **2.0.0**

Some users continue using **1.x.x** to avoid breaking changes.

If a bug is discovered in **1.0.5** it needs to be fixed for the **1.x.x** users requiring version change from **1.0.5** => **1.0.6**

In effect, this is branching.  I'd make a git branch for **1.x.x** users and continue using git's master branch for **2.x.x**

But how does this fit in with npm? Should I publish an older npm version **1.0.6**? In that case doesn't **1.0.6** become the latest while actually **2.0.0** should be the default when doing `npm install`.

I can't find branch related information for npm.  I'm sure the above is a common situation but I just can't find any info. Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You are on the right track - you want to publish `package@1.0.6` without updating the `latest` tag.  You can do this by supplying a `--tag <tagname>` argument to `npm publish` --

```
cd project
git checkout old-branch
grep version package.json
  "version": "1.0.5",
[make changes]
git commit
npm version patch
grep version package.json
  "version": "1.0.6",
npm publish --tag old-version
```

As long as you supply a `--tag <tagname>` argument to `npm publish`, the `latest` tag will not be updated, and people using `npm install <package>` or `npm install <package>@latest` will still get the 2.x version.

Note that the tagname has to share a namespace with version numbers, so it's best to choose a tagname that doesn't look like a semver version; avoid '1.0.6' or 'v1.0.6'.

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish
and: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-tags

Comment: This answer is very helpful! I thought, however, that I could run `npm i @mycompany/mypackage@beta` and it would install the package that was most recently published with the `beta` dist tag, but I got a "No matching version found" error.